# Arch_model rolling window forecasting

Tags: arch

I have used the below code to run a floating window forecast to predict variance:

```
index = returns.index
start_loc = 0
end_loc = np.where(index >= "2010-1-1")[0].min()
forecasts = {}
for i in range(20):
    sys.stdout.write(".")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    res = am.fit(first_obs=i, last_obs=i + end_loc, disp="off")
    temp = res.forecast(horizon=3).variance
fcast = temp.iloc[0]
forecasts[fcast.name] = fcast
print()
print(pd.DataFrame(forecasts).T)
```

Is there also a possibility to obtain a history / parameters (params) for each day in the rolling window? Is there a similar object as ARCHModelForecast for this?

I could not find this.